# Notify what text was changed in textview

Tags: java, android

How can I notify that a text has been changed in a dialog?

I am making a fingerprint, when it succeeds I would like to exchange the message displayed in the textview of it.

```
public void showDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_digital, null);
        TextView textFinger = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.text_finger);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
        alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        textFinger.setText(texto);
        dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonCancelar).setOnClickListener(view -> {
            fingerPrintAuthHelper.stopAuth();
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        });
}

@Override
public void onAuthSuccess(FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject) {
    texto = "Sucesso";
    alertDialog.show();
    presenter.sendData(bundle.getString(USER), bundle.getString(PASS));
    FragmentUtils.navigateTo(getActivity(), TermsOfUseFragment.TAG, new TermsOfUseFragment(), R.id.fragmentContainer);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to change the text of TextView after the authentication succeed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onAuthSuccess(FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject) {
    texto = "Sucesso";
    textFinger.setText(texto); //Change to this
    presenter.sendData(bundle.getString(USER), bundle.getString(PASS));
    FragmentUtils.navigateTo(getActivity(), TermsOfUseFragment.TAG, new TermsOfUseFragment(), R.id.fragmentContainer);
}
```